# How to repair drywall tape between ceiling and tiles on wall?

Tags: drywall, tile, joints, tape

I recently moved back to my own place after having rented it out for few years.  I noticed only later that the drywall joints in the inner corner of the ceiling of my tiled bathroom wall are completely peeling off. See the pictures.

I would like to fix this but not sure where to start since I can't tape an inner corner against a tiled wall. Instead I thought about just filling the gap and putting a regular flat joint on the edge of the ceiling. Do you think that'd work or suggest another solution?
[image: cracked tape]

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! Did you move into a rental or purchased place? In the US it matters, as in a rental, this isn't the kind of work you should be doing - it should be on the landlord. Please [edit] your post to specify. Once you've done that, spend a moment taking the [tour] to familiarize yourself with the differences between this place and most discussion forums.

Comment: Thanks, I edited to reflect i own the place and understand I will have to undertake the works. I looked for other threads but found none that addressed this issue of dealing with inner corner joints when the wall is tilted all the way up to the ceiling.

Comment: Small, unelaborate, **crown molding** would be the lazy man's way of dealing with it (it's what I would consider!).

Answer (score 1):

You could apply new joint compound between the tape and the drywall and attempt to re-adhere the existing tape to the ceiling. It could be reinforced further by applying a new strip of tape on top of the existing tape, such that the center of the new strip is approximately aligned to the edge of the original strip.

A comment suggested crown molding to simply cover the area. On the chance that you don't like the look of a small crown you could consider another profile. For example, a 1/8" by 1" flat rectangle would nearly disappear into the ceiling. Browse the millwork section at a lumber yard or home center for ideas.

Comment: Thanks so much to you and Steve for great suggestions. I like the crown idea as a workaround!